# During script recording using jmeter product is not being added to cart

Tags: jmeter

When i am trying to record my script in jmeter,it is not adding product into cart.I tried it manually which is working fine.Could anyone let me know why it is not adding to cart.

Comment: any update on this ? If answer was helpful it should be accepted so that it 's useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Switch in HTTP Test Script Recorder the implementation to Java and try again.

You may be facing an encoding issue:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56141